# How to find optimized combinations of values in input columns that produces the values in output column

Tags: data-mining, decision-trees, python-3.x, association-rules, pycaret

I have multiple input columns that produce an output column. I want to find optimized combinations of the values in the input columns that produce the values in the output column.

For eg:

[image: Like this table]

So, the output would be like:

CC -> Output 4

AA, XX -> Output 1

and so on.

I am trying to use association rule learning to find rules or relationships between multiple input columns and one output column (all textual columns). I have tried pycaret.arules but it is not available after pycaret==2.3.10 and this or below versions are not compatible with Python 3.10. So, I cannot use it.

Is there any other way to solve this problem. I tried decision trees, but I want something that fits exactly to my data without any extra nodes.

So far, I have looked into different apriori implementations from apyori, efficient-apriori etc. None of them are fitting to exactly what I want.